# Could you pls clarify me, Whether I can use MVC controller to acheive Restful service?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I am new to MVC & Web API. Could you pls clarify me the below question?

1. Is it possible to create Restful service using MVC controller (with out inheriting apicontroller class)?
2. What are ways to create the Restful service?
3. When & why to choose the webAPI?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer your question in general sense (following the general question),

REST is an *architectural style* while MVC and Web API are *architectural pattern*. *Architectural style* is a concept while *architectural pattern* is set of tools which are defined primarily to support, but not limited to, certain *architectural style*

1. That being said, it is **possible** create Restful service using MVC controller without, though MVC controller is not primarily aimed to create Restful service. In fact, a Web API controller is an MVC controller. So, in that sense MVC controller is more general.
2. With the same reasoning, then you can create Restful service by a couple of tools like:

   - WCF: Though this is primarily designed to support SOAP messaging over web, there is WCF REST developed to support making Restful services (with some overheads)
   - MVC: More general, having similarities with Web API. You can look other posts to find more of this out
   - Web API: Here you go! This is purposely designed for REST!
   - Some others which I might not be familiar with
3. Thus, we choose Web API when we want to create REST service, because this *architectural pattern* is purposely designed for that. If you use VS, the template for the solution is already there for you, making you easier to start your project.

Currently MVC and Web API have been combined in ASP.NET, so you can also use both of them whenever you feel needed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubts :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)